# Add a different drawing at the bottom of every page

Tags: graphics, header-footer, animations

I am writing my thesis and thought it would be fun to add a small animation at the footer of the pages. So you can see some movement when flipping the pages fast.

Is there a way to add a different small image to the bottom of every page? It could also be done a posteriori, once the document was compiled.

Comment: irrelevant but you gotta be careful with your thesis. People will read it and judge you based on it. stick with formal style.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done by inserting the following code coming from [`fancyhdr` user manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) (Section 19. *"A movie"*).

In the preamble please insert:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(5,0){\includegraphics{pic\thepage.ps}}
\end{picture}}
```

This will add to every page a picture named `pic<n>.ps` where `<n>` is the page number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for your valuable answer. However, it could be improved as following: giving a link to [official repo](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) instead of google search, using [markdown formating](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and actually detailing the core principle of the answer instead of just linking to it (what if the link breaks?).

Comment: @mario: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

Based on mario1000's answer, there is a very simple solution using the [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package by doing the following:

```
\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(5,0){\includegraphics{pic\thepage.ps}}
\end{picture}}
```

This will add to every page a picture named `pic<n>.ps` where `<n>` is the page number.

Comment: This isn't *based on* mario1000's answer, this **is** mario1000's answer.

Comment: @erik: regarding edits history, Aquiles' statement was true at the time he wrote it - even if it now looks less obvious (i.e. Mario updated his answer... based on Aquiles' one, that was itself based on Mario's original answer).

Comment: @ebo Thanks for pointing that out. Apologies to the OP.